# Activerecode HABTM primary key problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have to tables that have a many to many relationship.  I have created the correct table codesecure_project_tst_definition and it works.  I can join rows together by calling the codesecure_projects << method on a TstDefinition object.  The problem is that for some reason active record wants to use Codesecure_project_id as the id value for the codesecure_project_tst_definition table.  What am I doing wrong? How do I fix it so that when I call the codesecure_projects << method it does not try to set the id of the codesecure_project_tst_definition table?

I have posted the migrations below

```
class CreateCodesecureProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :codesecure_projects do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :lang

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :codesecure_projects
  end
end


class CreateTstDefinitions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :tst_definitions do |t|
      t.string :test_name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :tst_definitions
  end
end


class CreateCodesecureProjectsTstDefinitions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :codesecure_projects_tst_definitions do |t|
      t.references :codesecure_project
      t.references :tst_definition

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :codesecure_projects_tst_definitions
  end
end
```

The relevant parts of the models:

```
class TstDefinition < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :codesecure_projects
  has_many :tst_datas 

class CodesecureProject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :input_abstractions
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tst_definitions
```

Comment: Can you show us the class definitions with the association lines in?

Comment: I couldn't understand the problem.. post Tables schema.. like Gareth said.. posting the AR Model classes might help

Answer (score 4):

After some searching I actually found the answer, thanks to this blog post http://jimcortez.com/blog/?p=9.  I simply needed to remove the id column from the codesecure_projects_tst_definitions table.  So the migration now looks like this:

```
class CreateCodesecureProjectsTstDefinitions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :codesecure_projects_tst_definitions, :id => false do |t|
      t.references :codesecure_project
      t.references :tst_definition

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :codesecure_projects_tst_definitions
  end
end
```

Comment: I was just typing this up lol. You should also consider using a `has_many :through` association which makes the join table into a real join model. This was added 2 years ago [http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2006/04/21/habtm-vs-has_many-through/] but there's probably some more indepth references around